# Self-reference in Class literal, and instantiate with a DOM element

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get access to the Position X and Y of the element, created in Class literal (or any other way possible, like in object literal), and a method that uses these properties too, accessing their styles.

```js
class ObjectScene {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    let posX = this.element.offsetLeft;
    let posY = this.element.offsetTop;

    this.resetWall = () => {
      this.element.style.left = 'unset';
      this.element.style.right = '0px';
    }
  }
}

const wall = new ObjectScene(document.getElementById('wall'));
console.log(wall.posX);
```

```html
<div class="wall" id="wall"></div>
```

Is it because the posX and posY is not referencing the DOM element yet? i get undefined and NaN trying to console.log the properties.

I'm  doing it because i have like 3 functions using all the same properties,  position, reset position and stuff like that, but each one a different DOM element. So this was one way i thought of doing for dry code.

Comment: `let` creates a variable, not a property. You'd need `this.posX = ...`

Comment: Why do you use `this.element =` but `let posX =`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`posX`, `posY` just exist within the scope of the constructor. You actually create a variable and not a property of your object.

You could, for example, assign them to `this`, as you did it with `element`, and thus properly create a property of your object.

```js
class ObjectScene {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.posX = this.element.offsetLeft;
    this.posY = this.element.offsetTop;

    this.resetWall = () => {
      this.element.style.left = 'unset';
      this.element.style.right = '0px';
    }
  }
}

const wall = new ObjectScene(document.getElementById('wall'));
console.log(wall.posX);
```

```html
<div class="wall" id="wall"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! i can't believe it was only that, i used let instead of this because i mislead i guess, i thought that i could only use this in the constructor if the  property is in the parameter, thinking about it now makes no sense.

Comment: In that case I recommend you to read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) :)